# What does "p.º" mean?

Tags: abreviaturas

Primero, mi pregunta en español:

**¿Qué significa «p.º»?**

**Details in English:**

I saw this abbreviation for the first time in a prep book for a [**Diplomas de Español como Lengua Extranjera (DELE)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DELE) B2 exam.  Ordinarily, I might have just added it to my box of unsolved mysteries (few and far between thanks to the Spanish Language StackExchange), but since having failed the exam, I am now going over the preparation material with a fine-toothed comb.  I have looked high and low for this particular abbreviation to no avail.  Any ideas?

**Detalles en español:**

Vi esta abreviatura por primera vez en un libro de preparación para un examen del DELE B2.  Normalmente, puede que lo haya añadido a mi caja de misterios sin resolver (contadísimas gracias al Spanish Language Stack Exchange), pero desde que fallé el examen, estoy repasando los materiales minuciosamente.  He buscado esta abreviatura en particular por todas partes, en vano.  ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Lisa, could you please provide at least one sample sentence?  That would make it a stronger question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cuando necesites conocer a qué hace referencia una abreviatura hay una lista bastante extensa en el DPD: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/apendices/apendice2.html

Ahí verás que *p.º* es abreviatura de *paseo*. Se usa en los nombres de calles, al menos yo no conozco otros usos de esta abreviatura.

Ejemplos:

> P.º de Gracia → Paseo de Gracia
>   P.º de San Vicente → Paseo de San Vicente

Comment: ¡Gracias, blonfu!  Busqué por todas partes y lista después de lista sin éxito.  Aparentemente hay muchos rincones y grietas de la RAE con que todavía tengo que familiarizarme.